# Unable to Test Java sample code in unix

Tags: java, docusignapi

I am trying to test sample java code for `DocuSign(SignatureRequest.java)` in my Unix environment.  It works fine locally and also when I test it by giving all the jar files while running.

```
java -cp ".:./docusign/jars/*" docusign.oracle.apps.po.sign.SignatureRequest
```

But when I try to set the CLASSPATH with all the provided jar's. It throws me an error. I think there is some conflict. But I am not sure. Please help.

```
 java docusign.oracle.apps.po.sign.SignatureRequest
```

> Jun 15, 2017 8:36:46 AM com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors processErrorMessages
>   SEVERE: The following errors and warnings have been detected with resource and/or provider classes:
>     SEVERE: Missing dependency for field: javax.ws.rs.core.UriInfo com.sun.jersey.server.impl.template.ViewableMessageBodyWriter.ui
>     SEVERE: Missing dependency for field: com.sun.jersey.spi.template.TemplateContext com.sun.jersey.server.impl.template.ViewableMessageBodyWriter.tc
>   Exception in thread "main" com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors$ErrorMessagesException
>           at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processErrorMessages(Errors.java:170)
>           at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.postProcess(Errors.java:136)
>           at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processWithErrors(Errors.java:199)
>           at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.(Client.java:188)
>           at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.(Client.java:171)
>           at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.create(Client.java:683)
>           at com.docusign.esign.client.ApiClient.buildHttpClient(ApiClient.java:626)
>           at com.docusign.esign.client.ApiClient.(ApiClient.java:70)
>           at docusign.oracle.apps.po.sign.SignatureRequest.main(SignatureRequest.java:32)

Thaks
Bharat

Answer (score 1):

It worked after adding jersey-server-1.19.1.jar. thanks a lot